Why would the ideal observer make moral judgements?
Ideal observer theory states that an action is morally right/wrong if a theoretical, impartial, ideal observer has a positive or negative attitude towards said action, and that moral claims express propositions about the attitudes of said observer. However, wouldn't the existence of its attitudes diminish its impartiality and rationality? And why would it make moral judgements in the first place? What is the motivation for it to do so unless there is already moral truth outside of it?

oh, ethics really is aesthetics

@user66697 I'm asking why this ideal observer would make a moral judgement in the first place. This doesnt assume it exists

Good point, a common criticism of Firth's "disinterested" and "dispassionate" observers is that they are indifferent and morally impotent, see SEP. However, "ideal observer" is only meant as a heuristic discovery device. Morality itself may well be objective, but the question remains of how do we obtain trustworthy moral judgments. Firth's idea is that we have some primal moral intuition that gets obscured by ignorance, inaptitude, biases, etc., and this is an intellectual device for tapping into it.

@edelex, What's your source for "ideal observer theory"?

@Gerry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_observer_theory 'Ideal observer theory is the meta-ethical view which claims that ethical sentences express truth-apt propositions about the attitudes of a hypothetical ideal observer. In other words, ideal observer theory states that ethical judgments should be interpreted as statements about the reactions that a neutral and fully informed observer would have; "x is good" means "an ideal observer would approve of x".'

In a sense yes, the judgements of the ideal observer do demonstrate partiality, but it is the partiality of a rational, well-informed observer with no particular axe to grind. Clearly, the rational observer still has to make judgements, weighing the pros and cons of options, but the suggestion is that if you assume those judgements are made calmly and rationally by someone in possession of all the facts, that is as good a basis as any other for deeming that the judgements are 'morally right'.

But why does it have to make judgements?

The observer doesn't have to. The theory simply assumes that if the observer were to make such a judgement, that would be a good basis for determining whether something was morally right.

@user66697 I think we are at cross purposes. You and I are using partial and impartial in different ways, so I agree with you more than our words might suggest.

@MarcoOcram But if the ideal observer is rational and dispassionate, why would it even make a moral judgement even if forced to? Why would it not be most in-line with the characteristics of the ideal observer to withhold all judgement of actions?

@edelex you are arguing at cross purposes. The point being made is that if the ideal observer made the judgement, you could assume it was a sensible one. Your are now asking why would they make a judgement, which is irrelevant to the point being made.

@edelex anyway, why wouldn't they make a judgement? Suppose you are an ideal rational observer and I ask you what you think about a particular action- why would you refuse to tell me what you thought?

@MarcoOcram They have no reason to unless it fits in their characteristics, and it doesn't fit into impartiality unless they are simply referring to a pre-existing moral truth not determined by their attitudes

You are stubbornly missing the point. Good night.
